# jQuery click function on append elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, append

// Jade

```
.gj-funded-research.occ-group

  .occ

    h1.occ__reveal Funded Research

    .occ__hidden

      h3 Funded Research

      p Content

  .occ

    h1.occ__reveal Funded Research

    .occ__hidden

      h3 Funded Research

      p Content
```

// Angular

```
angular.module('core')
.directive('occGroup', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'AEC',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var occ = $('.occ'),
          occReveal = $('.occ__reveal'),
          occHidden = $('.occ__hidden'),
          occBack = $('<div/>').text('Back').addClass('occ__back'),
          doc = $(document)

      occHidden.append(occBack)

      occReveal.on('click', function() {
        $(this).siblings('.occ__hidden').addClass('show')
        console.log('occReveal clicked')
      })

      occBack.each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function() {
          occHidden.removeClass('show')
          console.log('occBack clicked')            
        })
      })

    }
  }

})
```

I'm appending a button element to every .occ-hidden element and then assigning a click function for each of those buttons, which removes a class from it's immediate parent .occ-hidden element. Currently the click function only works for the very last .occ element, meaning, when I click on the button element within the last .occ element then the stated class gets removed from .occ-hidden. But this is not the case for any preceding .occ elements. Is there something I need to do differently when dealing with append elements?

Comment: I saw you posted a question 1 day ago and someone created a CodePen demo for you .. so why you don't include the demo in your question??

Comment: Use ng-click and ng-class.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I see you point. In this case the issue I'm encountering now is separate from what I posted yesterday, even though it's the same code. The previous issue is now resolved, which is why I don't deem it necessary to reference that codepen.

Comment: @lux I am unable to use angular in that particular way simply because this code is to be used for a framework managed by Nation Builder.  There system doesn't allow developers to add extra angular code in the html, which is why I'm using this particular angular directive strictly using the class method.

Comment: @Sat can you use template in your directive to dynamically add HTML containing ng-click or that is forbidden as well? If you cannot manipulate the HTML then you shouldn't use an angular directive at all

Comment: @floribon I totally agree, and that would be the case if it were up to me, but unfortunately it's what I have to work with.

Comment: @Sat you are probably not grabbing the elements you think when you use jQuery.  Create one `occBack ` per `occ__hidden`, as currently `$('.occ__hidden')` will give you an array of all the matching element, on which you only append one element. The whole logic is messed up, browse each node one by one and console.log to make sure you are manipulating what you think. Create a jsfiddle or something if you want help with the code